# Как узнать сколько раз число кратное 5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть число 1001. Как можно узнать сколько раз оно будет кратное 5?

Comment: Число 1001 не кратно 5.

Comment: Ответ очевиден - ноль раз.

Comment: Я неправильно написал - Сколько чисел от 1 до 1001 будут кратны 5)

Comment: Ну значит исправьте текст вопроса. И заодно поясните, какие у вас трудности, потому что это выглядит как самые основы языка, описанные в любом учебнике

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот такой вариант.

```
    const multiple = (n, maxNum) => {
let count = 0; 
  for (let i = 0; i < maxNum; i++) {
if (i % n === 0) {
count++;
}
}
  return count;
}

multiple(5, 1001); //201
```

Comment: Круто, конечно... А не проще просто разделить?